# Moving variables in nested Loop JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```js
function transformEmployeeData(employeeData) {
  var arr = [];
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < employeeData.length; i++) {

    var personArr = employeeData[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < personArr.length; j++) {
      var key = personArr[j][0];
      var value = personArr[j][1];
      obj[key] = value;
    }
    arr.push(obj);
  }
  return arr;
}

input = [
  [
    ['firstName', 'Joe'],
    ['lastName', 'Blow'],
    ['age', 42],
    ['role', 'clerk']
  ],
  [
    ['firstName', 'Mary'],
    ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
    ['age', 36],
    ['role', 'manager']
  ]
];

var getData = transformEmployeeData(input);
console.log(getData);
```

And I want my result to be like this:

```
[
    {firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Blow', age: 42, role: 'clerk'},
    {firstName: 'Mary', lastName: 'Jenkins', age: 36, role: 'manager'}
]
```

So I moved `var obj = {};` into the first for loop, and I got the right result. But I still cannot figure out why I have to move it inside the loop? what is the difference? Please help, thank you!

Comment: `arr.push(obj)` doesn't make a copy of the object it just pushes a reference to the same object every time.

Comment: Read up on Object Mutation, here is a first link that I found: https://www.zeptobook.com/object-mutation-in-javascript/#why-original-object-mutated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't put it in the loop, you are defining a single object and are just modifying its contents within the loop body and pushing that single object into the array.

But, if you include it inside the loop, you create a new object each time the loop body executes (and the existing variable stops pointing to the previous object and now references the new one) and then push that new object into the array, resulting in multiple objects in your output.

Comment: Thank you so much! It confused me a lot but now I kinda get it. So I iterate the objects inside the first loop, every time it collects a new object, it will return to the ```obj={};``` which is outside of the loop and you get nothing after each loop. In the end, you only get the last obj, right?

Comment: @Ben You're welcome. Don't forget to up vote all helpful answers and consider marking this one as "the" answer by clicking the check mark at the top left of the question.

Comment: @Ben It doesn't "collect" a new object, it creates one. As opposed to working with a pre-existing one, which is what happens when the declaration is outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not add the object in the first loop, you are creating a single object for the whole function execution which can override previous properties of the first loop by the second one

Answer (score 0):

you can use `map` and `Object.fromEntries` for that

```js
function transformEmployeeData(employeeData) {
 return employeeData.map(Object.fromEntries)
}

input = [
  [
    ['firstName', 'Joe'],
    ['lastName', 'Blow'],
    ['age', 42],
    ['role', 'clerk']
  ],
  [
    ['firstName', 'Mary'],
    ['lastName', 'Jenkins'],
    ['age', 36],
    ['role', 'manager']
  ]
];

var getData = transformEmployeeData(input);
console.log(getData);
```

Comment: This is an answer in search of a question. The OP didn't ask for a way to make it work, the question was why does the location of the variable declaration matter?